# how to call function from ascx.cs in javascript using ajax call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I have created one control which has one function but I want to call that function with ajax call on any .aspx page or master page same as like calling  function from a code behind file,am fine with  codebehind file but stucked with calling function from acsx.cs file to any .aspx page/master page on which am including/registering that control.
this is my HTML

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="button" id="Button2" runat="server" value="Button" />
</div>
```

my ascx.cs code

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod()]
public static void myMethod(string text)
{
  Label1.text=text;
}
```

my ajax call whn am calling function from code behind file is like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Button2").click(function () {
        var text = $("#TextBox1").val();        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/myMethod",
            data: "{ text: '" + text + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: "true",
            cache: "false",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("success");
            },
            Error: function (x, e) {
                // On Error
            }
        });


    });
    });
```

in ajax call am calling function from codebehind thats why am puting  **url: "WebForm1.aspx/myMethod",** but am confused when about calling the function from .ascx.cs, like what will be a Url value for that because am simply including that control on my page like

```
<UC:userControl id="control1" runat="server" />
```

which I have included/registered on my page like
`<%@ Register TagPrefix="UC" TagName="userControl " src="~/Controls/Mycontrol.ascx" %>`

so here I'm confused with this url value
i tried url value(s) like

```
first-url: "Mycontrol.ascx/myMethod"

second-url: "WebForm1.aspx/Mycontrol.ascx/myMethod"
```

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to understand. And you should add the code of the stuff you have already tried.

Comment: i have updated my question check once